# элемент svg мерцает при наведении

Tags: html, css, svg

Есть группа svg-элементов `g` с идентификатором `g1` , в ней лежат элементы `path` . Для `g1` задан стиль:

```
#g1:hover {
display: none;
}
```

При наведении возникает проблема: `display:none` срабатывает не на всем поле, покрываемом `g1` и его дочерними элементами (в результате при перемещении курсора по данному полю экран в данной области как бы мерцает, переключаясь между состояниями отображения/сокрытия элемента). `@keyframes` не работают вообще. `svg`-файл импортирован в `html` через тег `svg`, создан в Inkscape, сохранен как оптимизированный svg-файл. С чем это может быть связано и на какой стадии допущена ошибка?
Весь код здесь: https://codepen.io/j_a_c_k_hammer/pen/oNWRpyp

Comment: наверное не трудно скопировать код,в вопрос, который у вас есть. Вопрос тогда будет более конкретный и на него вы сможете получить конкретный ответ-решение. В таком виде, как есть, вы вряд ли получите верный ответ

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Описание в вопросе и предоставленный код в Codepen несколько отличаются.

Я не нашёл `@keyframes` и `#g1`

Может быть это поможет?
По крайней мере  при наведении и движении курсора, мерцания нет

Вместо

```
 #g994:hover{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

используйте при наведении `opacity: 0;`

```html
  <style>
  #g994:hover{
    opacity: 0;
}
</style>
  <div id="coupe_container"><svg
            width="90.971069mm"
            height="111.14265mm"
            version="1.1"
            viewBox="0 0 90.971069 111.14265"
            id="svg97"
            sodipodi:docname="рисунок.svg"
            inkscape:version="1.1 (c68e22c387, 2021-05-23)"
            xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
            xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
            xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
           <defs
              id="defs22">
             <linearGradient
                id="linearGradient153800">
               <stop
                  stop-color="#ececec"
                  offset="0"
                  id="stop2" />
               <stop
                  stop-color="#e6e6e6"
                  offset="1"
                  id="stop4" />
             </linearGradient>
             <linearGradient
                id="linearGradient138356">
               <stop
                  stop-color="#b3b3b3"
                  offset="0"
                  id="stop7" />
               <stop
                  stop-color="#ececec"
                  offset="1"
                  id="stop9" />
             </linearGradient>
             <radialGradient
                id="radialGradient146724"
                cx="116.64"
                cy="159.61"
                r="29.903"
                gradientTransform="matrix(0.03188334,0.04413427,-0.01925113,0.06580623,67.913745,-61.679643)"
                gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
                xlink:href="#linearGradient138356" />
             <radialGradient
                id="radialGradient149510"
                cx="116.64"
                cy="159.61"
                r="29.903"
                gradientTransform="matrix(0.03188334,0.04413427,-0.01925113,0.06580623,89.505861,-61.679643)"
                gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
                xlink:href="#linearGradient138356" />
             <radialGradient
                id="radialGradient149520"
                cx="116.64"
                cy="159.61"
                r="29.903"
                gradientTransform="matrix(0.03188334,0.04413427,-0.01925113,0.06580623,100.30192,-61.679643)"
                gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
                xlink:href="#linearGradient138356" />
             <radialGradient
                id="radialGradient149610"
                cx="116.64"
                cy="159.61"
                r="29.903"
                gradientTransform="matrix(0.04906068,0.09322069,-0.02962292,0.13899119,-42.708958,-81.26846)"
                gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
                xlink:href="#linearGradient138356" />
             <radialGradient
                id="radialGradient149738"
                cx="116.64"
                cy="159.61"
                r="29.903"
                gradientTransform="matrix(0.03188334,0.04413427,-0.01925113,0.06580623,78.709803,-61.679643)"
                gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
                xlink:href="#linearGradient138356" />
             <radialGradient
                id="radialGradient151589"
                cx="116.64"
                cy="159.61"
                r="29.903"
                gradientTransform="matrix(0.04906068,0.09322069,-0.02962292,0.13899119,-50.926747,-81.26846)"
                gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
                xlink:href="#linearGradient138356" />
             <radialGradient
                id="radialGradient151593"
                cx="116.64"
                cy="159.61"
                r="29.903"
                gradientTransform="matrix(0.04071188,0.08996715,-0.02458147,0.13414079,-30.682118,-90.817402)"
                gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
                xlink:href="#linearGradient138356" />
             <radialGradient
                id="radialGradient151654"
                cx="116.64"
                cy="159.61"
                r="29.903"
                gradientTransform="matrix(0.04071188,0.08996715,-0.02458147,0.13414079,-63.037735,-90.817402)"
                gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
                xlink:href="#linearGradient138356" />
             <radialGradient
                id="radialGradient153802"
                cx="55.210999"
                cy="149.08"
                r="15.179"
                gradientTransform="matrix(1.3499437,-0.00835521,0.032795,3.2952826,-60.939048,-433.27919)"
                gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
                xlink:href="#linearGradient153800" />
             <radialGradient
                id="radialGradient155758"
                cx="55.210999"
                cy="149.08"
                r="15.179"
                gradientTransform="matrix(1.3499437,-0.00835521,0.032795,3.2952826,-6.4285255,-433.27919)"
                gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
                xlink:href="#linearGradient153800" />
           </defs>
           <rect
              x="0.43660432"
              y="0.38684416"
              width="90.10276"
              height="110.51003"
              fill="#ffffff"
              stroke="#000006"
              stroke-linejoin="round"
              stroke-opacity="0.78544"
              stroke-width="0.680567"
              id="rect24" />
           <g
              fill="none"
              stroke="#000000"
              id="g32"
              transform="matrix(0.53258521,0,0,0.46019001,-11.02889,-13.461654)">
             <path
                d="m 21.528,257.01 h 168.72"
                stroke-width="1.2373"
                id="path26" />
             <path
                d="m 21.061,42.889 h 170.59"
                stroke-width="1.2441"
                id="path28" />
             <path
                d="m 31.81,42.463 v 214.55"
                stroke-width="1.2652"
                id="path30" />
           </g>
           <path
              d="M 85.315774,6.2754353 V 105.20708"
              fill="#c86649"
              stroke-width="0"
              id="path34" />
           <rect
              x="33.201244"
              y="7.1852317"
              width="11.382943"
              height="52.162537"
              fill="#ffa1a1"
              stroke="#880a06"
              stroke-width="0.42698"
              id="rect40"
              style="stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-opacity:0.78544" />
           <rect
              x="46.644764"
              y="7.1870713"
              width="11.626867"
              height="52.157932"
              fill="#ffa1a1"
              stroke="#880a06"
              stroke-width="0.431514"
              id="rect42"
              style="stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-opacity:0.78544" />
           <rect
              x="32.735767"
              y="61.388248"
              width="25.755289"
              height="9.318388"
              id="rect45"
              style="fill:#a91d1d;stroke:#ff772f;stroke-width:0.660913;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-opacity:0.78544" />
           <rect
              x="32.735767"
              y="72.184311"
              width="25.755289"
              height="9.318388"
              id="rect47"
              style="fill:#a91d1d;stroke:#ff772f;stroke-width:0.660913;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-opacity:0.78544" />
           <rect
              x="32.984486"
              y="82.98037"
              width="25.755289"
              height="9.318388"
              id="rect49"
              style="fill:#a91d1d;stroke:#ff772f;stroke-width:0.660913;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-opacity:0.78544" />
           <rect
              x="32.984486"
              y="93.776421"
              width="25.755289"
              height="9.318388"
              id="rect51"
              style="fill:#a91d1d;stroke:#ff772f;stroke-width:0.660913;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-opacity:0.78544" />
           <rect
              transform="rotate(90)"
              x="67.964371"
              y="-48.157303"
              width="1.4599068"
              height="4.0914259"
              fill="url(#radialGradient146724)"
              id="rect55"
              style="fill:url(#radialGradient146724);stroke:#d9c7a7;stroke-width:0.38882;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round" />
           <rect
              transform="rotate(90)"
              x="89.55648"
              y="-48.157303"
              width="1.4599068"
              height="4.0914259"
              fill="url(#radialGradient149510)"
              id="rect57"
              style="fill:url(#radialGradient149510);stroke:#d9c7a7;stroke-width:0.38882;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round" />
           <rect
              transform="rotate(90)"
              x="100.35254"
              y="-48.157303"
              width="1.4599068"
              height="4.0914259"
              fill="url(#radialGradient149520)"
              id="rect59"
              style="fill:url(#radialGradient149520);stroke:#d9c7a7;stroke-width:0.38882;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round" />
           <rect
              transform="scale(-1)"
              x="-42.62907"
              y="-52.699867"
              width="2.2464445"
              height="8.6419077"
              fill="url(#radialGradient149610)"
              stroke="#8a6e3e"
              stroke-width="0.700964"
              id="rect63"
              style="fill:url(#radialGradient149610);stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round" />
           <rect
              transform="rotate(90)"
              x="78.760422"
              y="-48.157303"
              width="1.4599068"
              height="4.0914259"
              fill="url(#radialGradient149738)"
              stroke="#d9c7a7"
              stroke-width="0.38882"
              id="rect65"
              style="fill:url(#radialGradient149738);stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round" />
           <rect
              transform="scale(-1)"
              x="-50.841534"
              y="-52.699867"
              width="2.2464445"
              height="8.6419077"
              fill="url(#radialGradient151589)"
              stroke-width="0.700964"
              id="rect67"
              style="fill:url(#radialGradient151589);stroke:#8a6e3e;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round" />
           <g
              id="g994">
             <rect
                x="8.2400427"
                y="6.3651724"
                width="23.72028"
                height="98.379417"
                fill="#ffe7e7"
                stroke="#000006"
                stroke-width="0.506255"
                id="rect36"
                style="stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-opacity:0.78544" />
             <rect
                transform="scale(-1)"
                x="-30.615013"
                y="-63.247421"
                width="1.8641548"
                height="8.3404837"
                fill="url(#radialGradient151593)"
                stroke-width="0.284019"
                id="rect69"
                style="fill:url(#radialGradient151593);stroke:#8a6e3e;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round" />
             <rect
                x="10.144035"
                y="9.4162321"
                width="16.67684"
                height="91.080803"
                fill="url(#radialGradient153802)"
                stroke-width="0.80874"
                id="rect73"
                style="fill:url(#radialGradient153802);stroke:#8a6e3e;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round" />
           </g>
           <g
              id="g989">
             <rect
                x="59.762337"
                y="6.3545885"
                width="23.72028"
                height="98.379417"
                fill="#ffe7e7"
                stroke="#000006"
                stroke-width="0.506255"
                id="rect38"
                style="stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-opacity:0.78544" />
             <rect
                transform="scale(-1)"
                x="-62.973824"
                y="-63.247421"
                width="1.8641548"
                height="8.3404837"
                fill="url(#radialGradient151654)"
                stroke-width="0.284019"
                id="rect71"
                style="fill:url(#radialGradient151654);stroke:#8a6e3e;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round" />
             <rect
                x="64.656792"
                y="9.4162321"
                width="16.67684"
                height="91.080803"
                fill="url(#radialGradient155758)"
                stroke-width="0.80874"
                id="rect75"
                style="fill:url(#radialGradient155758);stroke:#8a6e3e;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round" />
           </g>
           <g
              fill="#f8f6d3"
              stroke-width="0"
              id="g91"
              transform="matrix(0.53258521,0,0,0.46019001,-11.02889,-13.461654)">
             <path
                d="M 181.87,149.95 V 43.74 h 7.6717 V 256.16 H 181.87 Z"
                id="path81" />
             <path
                d="m 144.36,43.423 c 6.1226,-0.06739 16.007,-0.06731 21.966,1.55e-4 5.9586,0.06748 0.94926,0.12261 -11.132,0.12252 -12.081,-8.7e-5 -16.956,-0.05528 -10.834,-0.12268 z"
                id="path83" />
             <path
                d="m 22.696,36.491 v -5.5451 h 166.85 v 11.09 H 22.696 Z"
                id="path85" />
             <path
                d="M 22.696,149.95 V 43.74 h 8.4124 V 256.16 H 22.696 Z"
                id="path87" />
             <path
                d="m 22.696,263.63 v -5.7584 h 166.85 v 11.517 H 22.696 Z"
                id="path89" />
           </g>
           <path
              d="M 86.082697,6.2215931 V 104.49977"
              fill="none"
              stroke="#000000"
              stroke-width="0.584673"
              id="path93" />
         </svg>
         
        </div>
```

Comment: Все работает. С @keyframes разобрался сам.